# Test not work using jest but using jasmine and karma works, ¿What is the problem?

Tags: angular, jasmine, jestjs, karma-jasmine

I’m using [Nx](https://nx.dev/angular) tool to manage my projects, [formly](https://formly.dev/) to manage my forms and [transloco](https://github.com/ngneat/transloco) for my translations.

By default, when I created my library is configured with jest as a test runner but my test does not work with that  because apparently the value never is translated. Then I created another library with karma as a test runner and copy all my code from the library that is configured with jest to my new library and the test works correctly. I don't know what is the problem, I and want to use jest to test my code.

## Versions

- Angular 10
- Transloco 2.17.5
- Formly 5.0.0
- Jest 25.2.3
- jest-preset-angular 8.1.2

## Testing tools setup code

The for the setup of jest and jasmine with karma is the default generated by nx

### Code for jest

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular';
```

### Code for jasmine with karma

```js
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

## Code that I want to test

### Template code

```html
<h1>{{ 'Audience.Title' | transloco }}</h1>
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <formly-form [form]="form" [fields]="formFields"></formly-form>
</form>
```

### Formly fields configuration code

```js
import { FormlyFieldConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core';

export const FORM_FIELDS: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    type: 'input',
    id: 'name',
    templateOptions: {
      translate: true,
      label: 'Forms.GeneralData.Name',
      placeholder: 'Forms.GeneralData.Name',
      required: true
    },
  },
];
```

### Component code

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FORM_FIELDS } from './form-fields';

@Component({
  selector: 'taskit-general-data',
  templateUrl: './general-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./general-data.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class GeneralDataComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  formFields = FORM_FIELDS;
}
```

### Test code

```js
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TRANSLOCO_SCOPE, TranslocoService } from '@ngneat/transloco';
import { FORMLY_CONFIG } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import {
  FormlyConfigurationModule,
  registerChildTranslateExtension,
} from '@taskit/taskit-platform/configuration/formly';
import { getTranslocoModule } from '@taskit/taskit-platform/configuration/transloco';

import es from '../../i18n/es.json';
import { FORM_FIELDS } from './form-fields';
import { GeneralDataComponent } from './general-data.component';

describe('GeneralDataComponent', () => {
  let component: GeneralDataComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GeneralDataComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        getTranslocoModule({ 'audience/es': es }),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormlyConfigurationModule,
      ],
      declarations: [GeneralDataComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TRANSLOCO_SCOPE,
          useValue: { scope: 'audience', alias: 'Audience' },
        },
        {
          provide: FORMLY_CONFIG,
          multi: true,
          useFactory: registerChildTranslateExtension,
          deps: [TranslocoService, TRANSLOCO_SCOPE],
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GeneralDataComponent);
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.formFields = FORM_FIELDS;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Should display correct title', () => {
    const titleElement = debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
    const title = titleElement.nativeElement.textContent;
    expect(title).toBe('Datos generales');
  });

  it('Should display correct label', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GeneralDataComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const text = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('label[for="name"]'))
      .nativeElement.textContent;

    expect(text.trim()).toBe('Nombre de audiencia');
  });
});
```

## Result using jest

[image]

## Result using jasmine with jest

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your it, you dont need

```
 const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GeneralDataComponent);
fixture.detectChanges();
```

because of it is in the beforeEach. It seems that the translation dont work.

Are you sure you want to test the rendering of formly? Formly is an external libraray and i would not test an external libraray. Also i think that this is a test case for e2e testing, e.g. with cypress.

Comment: Thanks, yes, probably the test case is not the better but my question is related with: Why when I run my test using jest fails and using jasmine with karma works successfully?

Comment: I think the problem is the dom in jest:
Jest is a DOM-less(!) simple JavaScript testing framework. It does not rely on browsers, DOM, or any JavaScript framework.

Jasmine uses the dom!